# Segmenattion fault using malloc , array of structures for mergesort

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, structure, mergesort

This code tries to apply merge sort on an array of structures and sort it.There is segmentation fault in mergesort function which i'm uable to predict why. I've attached the output as well and if anything is needed then please let me know.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node node;

struct node{
int index; // record-key
char fname[20], lname[20], dob[20], location[20], dept[20];
}demo,delta;


node delta ={-1,'a','a','a','a','a'};

void merge(node [], int, int, int );
void mergesort(node [], int , int );

void mergesort(node a[], int start, int end){

    int mid = (start+end)/2;
    if(start<end){
        mergesort(a,start,mid);
        mergesort(a,mid+1,end);
        merge(a,start,mid,end);
    }
}

void merge(node a[], int start, int mid, int end){
    node *b = malloc(sizeof(demo)*end*2);  //creating two arrays 
    node *c = malloc(sizeof(demo)*end*2);
    int j=0,k=0,i=0,e=0,f=0;

    for(i=start;i<mid+1;i++){   //storing first half of main array into b
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    b[i+1]=delta;    //this is a check value used for checking the length in a loop below 
    for(k=mid+1;k<end+1;k++){   //storing second part of main array into c
        c[j]=a[k];
        j++;
    }
    c[j+1]=delta;  //this is just a check value to check length

    for(i=start;i<end+1;i++){
        if(b[e].index==delta.index){    //if array b ends
            while(c[f].index!=delta.index){
                a[i]=c[f];               //copy remaining contents of c into a
                i++;
                f++;
            }
            break;
        }
        if(c[f].index==delta.index){             //if c ends
            while(b[e].index!=delta.index){    //copy remaining contents of b into a
                a[i]=b[e];
                i++;
                e++;
            }
            break;
        }

        if(b[e].index>c[f].index){    //compring first element of both b and c and overriding smaller value in main array
            a[i]=c[f];
            f++;
        }
        else if(b[e].index<=c[f].index){     //compring first element of both b and c and overriding smaller value in main array
            a[i]=b[e];
            e++;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<end+1;i++){
        printf("arr index: %d \n",a[i].index);    //just for checking
    }

}



int main(int argc ,char *argv[]){
    printf("entered in main\n");
    char temp[20];
    int i;

    FILE *fp =fopen(argv[1],"r");
    // printf("bakri\n");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("file not opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    node demo;
    printf("demo made %ld\n",sizeof(demo));
    int var = atoi(argv[2]);

    node *arr  = malloc(sizeof(demo)*var*2);
    if(arr==NULL){
        printf("arr is null\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("array made\n");

    for(i=0;i<(atoi(argv[2]));i++){
        fgetc(fp);
        fscanf(fp,"%s %s %s %s %s %s",temp,arr[i].fname,arr[i].lname,arr[i].dob,arr[i].location,arr[i].dept);
        arr[i].index=atoi(temp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(i=0;i<atoi(argv[2]);i++){
        printf("\n%d",arr[i].index);
    }

    int len = atoi(argv[2]);
    mergesort(arr,0,len-1);

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        printf("%d \n",arr[i].index);
    }

return 0;
}
```

The output is -

```
entered in main
demo made 104
array made

28053
31163
3786
33086
16355
4792
26524
21076
21367
27286arr index: 28053 
arr index: -414853824 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: You allocate `sizeof(demo) * end`. If you have a low upper part with start=99000 mid=99500 and end=100000, you allocate 100000 but need only 1000. b is filled starting at start, c is filled starting at 0 but later you access b and c in a loop `for(i=start;i<end+1;i++){`. The loops `while(c[i].index!=delta.index){` don't test for `i<end`

Comment: @Holger i've looked into it and changed the code , now the output is shown

Comment: `b = malloc(sizeof(demo) * ((mid+1)-start+1))` `c = malloc(sizeof(demo) * (end-(mid+1)+1))` After the loops i and j are already behind the last.. `b[i] = delta;` `c[j] = delta` You shouldn't do so much `+1`. `for(i=start;i<=mid` `for(j=mid+1; j<=end`

Answer (score 2):

The max index of the array you allocate with:

```
node *c = malloc(sizeof(demo)*end);
```

is `end - 1`. And then you have:

```
for(k=mid+1;k<end+1;k++){
    c[j]=a[k];
    j++;
}
```

You're going out of the boundaries of the array, which will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: I changed the size of c and b arrays to end*2 but still now segmentation fault appears and garbage values of array index(2nd print output) keeps on printing.

Comment: Check your loops and make sure you never get out of the array boundaries. This is the most common reason for segmentation faults, at least from my experience.